# How to modify date format taken from Wordpress API?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, api

By taking data from Wordpress API I'm getting date/time this way - **2019-11-29 19:00:00**

How to modify it by making look like this - **November 29, 2019 19:00**

*HTML:*

`<p class="date">DATE</p>`

*JS:*

```
const date = postCopy.querySelector(".date");
date.textContent = post.event_date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the `toLocaleDateString()` method available in vanilla JS.

Relevant doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

```js
let initialDate = "2019-11-29 19:00:00"

let formattedDate = new Date(initialDate).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: '2-digit',
  hour: "2-digit",
  minute: "2-digit",
  hour12: false

})
console.log(formattedDate)
```

If you don't like this approach, take a look at the 51 solutions proposed in this similar question: [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Thank you! Solved this little problem for my project